# Postgres - how to typecast sum(bigint) to bigint?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, biginteger, bigdecimal, bigint

I have a Postgres 8.2 table with columns defined as `bigint` datatype.

When I do `sum(column)` the return type is `numeric`. I want to force type cast the summation to be `bigint` since I know for sure that the result will not exceed the max value of `bigint`. I was able to achieve this using a subquery like this:

`select T.big_col_total::bigint from (select sum(big_col) as big_col_total from big_table) T;`

Is there a way to do this without using the subquery, i.e., can I typecast the `sum` directly somehow? I tried a couple of ways and both result in a syntax error.

(background: I'm running this query from Hibernate so it is important for me the keep the return data type from the query limited to BigInteger. bigint + bigint = numeric (BigDecimal on the Java side)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use:

```
select sum(big_col)::bigint as total 
from big_table
```

And you should upgrade to a supported version (e.g. 9.x) as soon as possible.

Comment: I get this error running the above query from Hibernate. 

`org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:bigint, :]`

If I change `sum(big_col)::bigint` to `sum(big_col) :: bigint` (with spaces in b/w), I still get the same error.

Hibernate seems to think :bigint is named parameter, any idea how to get around this? Thanks!

Comment: @svhyd: Try `cast(sum(big_col) AS bigint)` instead. It seems to fail because the colon (`:`) has a special meaning in Hiberante. You would have to escape the character or use the presented alternate syntax instead.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

`select cast(sum(big_col) AS bigint) AS total from big_table`